# Como criar webservice JAX-RS REST Service e consumir com aplicação android?

Tags: android, web-service, http-request

Criei um JAX-RS REST Service, com uma função que me retorna um JsonObject, consigo recuperar essa informação no navegador por meio da [URL](http://localhost:8080/Restful/aluno), mas não consigo recuperá-la em uma aplicação android. Como faço para configurar corretamente o Web Service para que eu possa ter acesso aos dados na minha aplicação?

```
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
public String getJson() {
    return "{\"estado\":\"São Paulo \",\"nacionalidade\":\"Brasil \",\"nome\":\"Fulano de Tal \"}";
}
```

Resposta no navegador acessando a [URL](http://localhost:8080/Restful/aluno):

```
{"estado":"Acre ","nacionalidade":"Brasil ","nome":"Fulano de Tal  "}
```

Android:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);          
    new HttpAsyncTask().execute("http://localhost:8080/Restful/aluno");
}

public static String GET(String url){
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String result = "";
    try {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));

        inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

        if(inputStream != null)
            result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
        else
            result = "Não funcionou!";

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    return result;
}

private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line = "";
    String result = "";
    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        result += line;

    inputStream.close();
    return result;

}

private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        return GET(urls[0]);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Tem resultado? "+result.length());
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Received: \n" + result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
}
```

No Log o resultado do tamanho dessa string recuperada é 0, e o resultado de response é:

```
Connection to http://localhost:8080/refused
```

Pretendo não apenas recuperar informações textuais, quero recuperar pdfs por meio desse Web Service.

Comment: Já tentou usar o IP/domínio da máquina onde está rodando o WS no lugar de `localhost`?

Comment: Era isso @Bruno César conseguí recuperar, obrigado. Mas com relação ao pdf, qual a melhor forma de recuperá-lo na app e armazená-lo?

Comment: Você já tentou alguma coisa, como implementar o serviço no servidor? Alguma coisa na forma de recuperar no app ou ainda está procurando formas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para realizar a comunicação entre o App e o WebService modifiquei o Ip/domínio que era passado no método execute() da HttpAsyncTask.

Ele estava assim:

```
new HttpAsyncTask().execute("http://localhost:8080/Restful/aluno");
```

O que ocorre é que o Emulador do android está executando em IP diferente na rede, certo? Assim a Aplicação Android está em um Ip diferente do WebService, que *está localizado localmente em sua máquina*. Assim, o IP passado anteriormente estava referenciando o próprio IP do android na rede, quando era para ser o IP do WebService.

Ao iniciar meu WebService ele estava rodando no IP: "192.168.0.3" na porta "8080", assim só troquei o ip que estava como "localhost" para o Ip do WebService.

```
new HttpAsyncTask().execute("http://192.168.0.3:8080/Restful/aluno");
```

A única alteração foi incluída no método onCreate abaixo:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    new HttpAsyncTask().execute("http://192.168.0.3:8080/Restful/aluno");
}
```

Obrigado pela ajuda @Caio_césar

Answer (score 2):

Para consumir seu `WebService` você poderia trabalhar da seguinte maneira:

```
public class testeREST
{
private String          URL_WS;
//variaveis de contexto
//definiria o metodo a ser acessado no seu webService("Path")
private final String    metodo  = "teste/";

public List<teste> listarTeste() throws Exception
{
   //pegaria a instancia do seu webservice
    ConexaoWebService conexaoWebService = ConexaoWebService.getInstance();

    //validaria a conexão

 }  
}
//aqui você poderia montar sua url de conexao 
URL_WS = "metodos para obter sua url  ex:192.168.0.200:8080/WebserviceTeste;
```

Depois recuperar seu `JsonObject`

```
String[] resposta = new WebServiceCliente().get(URL_WS + metodo);
    List<Teste> testeWeb = new ArrayList<Teste>();
    if (resposta[0].equals("200"))
    {
 //utilizando o Gson você consegue criar objetos a partir de Strings em Json
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        JsonArray array = parser.parse(resposta[1]).getAsJsonArray();

        //cria um novo objeto a ser carregado 
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
        {
            Teste testando= gson.fromJson(array.get(i), Teste.class);

            TesteImportadoWS testeImportadoWS = new TesteImportadoWS (testeImportadoWS .getEstado());
            testeWeb.add(testeImportadoWS );
        }
     return testeWeb;
    }
```

Com isso você teria uma lista carregada com todos os dados que você desejar vindo via `WebService` para trabalhar.

[Link para documentação do Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)